# Проблема с многократным вызовом функции

Tags: c++

Пишу программу матричных вычислений. Соответственно, каждый шаг выполняет определённая функция, как и функция вывода в файл. Допустим у меня в функции вывода в файл есть одномерный массив для названия этого файла. Как сделать так, чтобы программа у меня ОДИН РАЗ запросила его название и запомнила внутри функции, чтобы я не писал название этого файла с каждым вызовом функции

Comment: Самое простое - заведите глобальную переменную и запишите имя в нее

Comment: Ещё лучше сделать класс, который будет хранить имя файла и иметь функцию запроса имени. Негоже одной функции и имя файла спрашивать, и данные считать.

Comment: Используйте статическую переменную в функции, например.

Comment: я тоже вначале в своем ответе такое написал, но потом одумался. Если имя файла нужно поменять, то придется потанцевать.

Comment: @KoVadim Это да. Но вы совершенно правы в том, что в одну функцию валить все нехорошо. По мне - ей лучше передавать ссылку на уже открытый файл...